# tried to run on windows xp sp3 ( exe from windows server os)

Tags: visual-c++

I compiled mfc program using vc2008 on windows server os. I tried to run exe on windows xp sp3. I am getting error as "This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.". what do i do for solve this.

Thanks,
KAM

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are targeting x86, not x64.

Comment: hi Alex Farber,

I installed VC++ 2008 runtime. still i am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Install VC++ 2008 runtime on destination computer:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en

Comment: is any other way to run without install vc++ 2008?

Comment: You don't need to install VC++ 2008, only runtime libraries. This is relatively small installation.

Comment: You need also to select correct runtime version: for 32 or 64 bit, with correct service pack. If your program has other runtime dependencies, install required third-party libraries. Use Release and not Debug build. Use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to detect what libraries are missing.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is usually associated with a bad `.manifest` file of the application. For example, if you have a "foo.exe" application and you put a "foo.exe.manifest" file in the same folder with random content, then you will get this error.

If you are accessing the application via a network share, then you might be running into [KB 316625](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316625). Check that you really have service pack 3 on the XP computer.